# Is there a way to call java methods in actionscript 3?

Tags: java, flash, actionscript-3

I want to know how to call a method in a java/class file from within my flash program so that I can navigate through files easier, and then have it return a string or integer. Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to have a separate Java applet and route communication through some appropriate Javascript glue using `ExternalInterface` on the Flash side and `netscape.javascript.JSObject` on the Java side. (The latter appears to provide some degree of cross-browser support despite its name).

Answer (score 0):

ExternalInterface is one option, as Henning mentions.

If you're planning to use AIR, have a look at the [Merapi](http://code.google.com/p/merapi/) project.
Also, with AIR 2.x you can try [NativeProcess](http://www.google.co.uk/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=air%20nativeprocess#sclient=psy&hl=en&source=hp&q=air%20nativeprocess%20java&pbx=1&oq=air%20nativeprocess%20java&aq=f&aqi=g-sv1&aql=&gs_sm=e&gs_upl=5242l5904l0l6017l5l4l0l0l0l0l253l649l0.1.2l3l0&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.&fp=edfb022449c760a8&biw=1238&bih=707).

If you're thinking about basic Java on the server side, either try basic [Socket](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/Socket.html) communication (as3 supports XML and binary Sockets). For larger scopes have a look at [Blaze DS](http://opensource.adobe.com/wiki/display/blazeds/BlazeDS) and/or [Spring Flex](http://www.springsource.org/spring-flex).

HTH